# How to run Python 3 Pyinstaller when I have Pyinstaller installed for both python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am on a windows machine. I wrote my application in python 3. I have Pyinstaller installed for both python 2 and 3. How do I call python 3 pyinstaller?

Comment: It depends on where/how you installed pyinstaller. You can always open the cmd and specify the full path to the correct version, but we cannot tell you the fullpath if you don't tell us how you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you'd need to do is set the path for your python environment to point to the python3 install location.  You'd then just use the `pip3 install pyinstaller` command and it should run.  You can use the command `pyinstaller --version` to confirm.